Why does Boost emphasise thread-safety for distinct objects?
As per this official page, which says that (emphasis mine):

Thread Safety
Distinct objects: Safe.
Shared objects:
Safe, with the specific exceptions of the restart()
and notify_fork() functions. Calling restart() while there are
unfinished run(), run_one(), run_for(), run_until(), poll() or
poll_one() calls results in undefined behaviour. The notify_fork()
function should not be called while any io_context function, or any
function on an I/O object that is associated with the io_context, is
being called in another thread.

In general, when discussing thread safety, we pay attention to the behaviour of the same object read/written in mutiple threads.
Why is the thread-safety for distinct objects emphasised?

Because there are hidden dependencies on shared data or processes. In this case there are no such dependencies so they chose to be explicit about it.

That^. For example, rand is notoriously thread-unsafe despite there being no apparent object.

you should provide some context. Apart from the tag, nowhere you mention that you are talking about boost

@PasserBy Thank you for the comment. But I really can't figure out the relation with my quetion.

They talk to you in terms of the public interface of the library. What the library does internally they have to consider for the guarantess they provide you, but they need not tell you all the gory details.
A silly counter example:
struct bar {
    private:
        static int foo;  // defined elsewhere
    public:
        int do_something() const { 
            foo+=1;
            return foo;
        }
 };

As a user I only need to know that do_something foos the bar, but how it is implemented internally is up to the implementation. In the documentation I'd expect that the library tells me that it is not safe to call do_something on two distinct objects concurrently.

If I undertand you correctly. For the struct bar, it's thread-safe for a single object while not thread-safe for distinct objects.  Am I right?

In this case it is not safe for both single and distinct objects. I think @463035818_is_not_an_ai was trying to demonstrate that even distinct objects might be thread unsafe due to some implementation details (even though they seem safe at a shalow glance), and so the documentation is mentioning this aspect.

@John no, its is not thread safe for any two objects to concurrently increment foo. I edited to make it more clear

@John ... and I forgot the const, which actually makes the method look as if it was safe to call it concurrently. One really shouldnt write code like that when multithreading is aimed for. Anyhow, the example is merely to illustrate that there can be a case. A realistic one would be more or less the same but less short and clear

@463035818_is_not_an_ai it is also not thread safe for a single shared instance, isn't it (if do_something is called by multiple threads) ? I think this is what the OP was asking about in the first comment below your answer. I tried to answer in my comment right below it.

@wohlstad what I said. "any two instances" can be twice the same instance. Not a native speaker here. Did I make it less clear? Though, imho it is out of scope of the quesiton which is about documentation mentioning thread safety among distinct objects.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai It is clear to me. But I'm not sure if it's clear to the OP (reading their first comment). Maybe they think 2 instances means separate ones. let's see if the OP still has a doubt.

@wohstad I rolled back my edit, because now it answers the question as stated, and their question in the comment is answered in the comment.

Anyway IMHO your answer offers a good explanation why the documentation is mentioning the issue of distinct objects explicitly (and I already voted).

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Thanks to you and @wohlstad. I fully understand it now that it's not thread-safe when multiple threads are readig/writing with the same object of struct bar since there is a static member variable named foo which would may be read/written by multiple threads. Am I right? If I miss something, please let me know.


In general, when discussing thread safety, we pay attention to the behaviour of the same object read/written in mutiple threads.

You are thinking about thread safety wrong.
Thread safety is a relational property of two (and sometimes more) pieces of code.  Two pieces of code can be thread safe relative to each other.  Thread safety isn't a property of an object instance.
Now, guaranteeing thread safety is much harder than pointing out when it is unsafe.  So most discussions about thread safety in documentation will talk about when use of this library causes lack of thread safety.
In this case, boost saying that using two different instances of this object type will not cause two pieces of your code that where thread safe to become thread unsafe.
This can happen; for example, two objects that both write to the same stream could have thread safety problems, or two objects that both interact with the same cache could have thread safety problems.
As a concrete example, two iterators into a std container have complex thread safety issues.
Knowing that distinct objects are not going to cause a problem is important.  It also means that if you use a different instance of this object in each thread, you don't have to know more about how this object works to know it isn't going to cause thread safety issues!
The key to making multi-threaded programs scale is eliminating having to think about thread safety issues.
For a single object being interacted with in 2 threads, it again highlights the methods that could cause thread safety issues.  If you avoid those methods you again don't have to add extra concerns about thread safety to your code - if it was thread safe without this library, it is thread safe with this library use.
Objects are not thread safe; certain operations on objects are relationally thread safe to other operations.
When you try to think of thread safety as being a property of an object, you end up with a clunky lock-based guard around specific objects; and lock-based thread safety doesn't compose.  Smaller lock-based thread safety procedures composed into larger ones can introduce thread-based failure problems.
